# what happens before didFinishLaunching as my iPad application is taking almost 7-8 seconds launching on ios 6.0.1

Tags: ipad, ios6, launching-application

Launching application after booting iPad takes almost 7-8 seconds on ios 6.0.1 but it's running fine on ios5. It hangs somewhere before coming to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:.I've no idea what's happening as it loads fine in all cases except i reboot iPad & launch the application.

while checking in Device Console,It starts to look up SecTurstEvaluate which takes around 7-8 seconds then goes to main() but  in ios 5.x it starts loading within a second.

Comment: You're doing networking in that method on the main thread, right?

Comment: nothing..just loading view controller.

Comment: it is taking time before coming into didFinishLaunching